# Orientation on manifolds

Tags: general-topology, differential-geometry, definition, differential-topology, orientation

I am trying to understand the definitions here. In many books (say Tu or even Guillemin-Pollack) an orientation on a manifold is an assignment to affix $+1$ and $-1$ to classes of (tangent) basis. It is proven in nearly every differential geometry book that connected orientable manifolds admits exactly two orientations.

Here is what I don't get, since you are assigning only $\{\pm 1\}$, how can it make sense to talk about anything but more than or fewer than two orientations? It only otherwise make senses to talk about not oriented right?

Removing the connectedness, can you even talk about, say three orientations?

Comment: For ${}-{}\ {}-{}$ you can have $\leftarrow{}\ {}\leftarrow$, $\leftarrow{}\ {}\rightarrow$, $\rightarrow{}\ {}\leftarrow$ and $\rightarrow{}\ {}\rightarrow$ as orientations.

Comment: It is not true that any connected manifold admits exactly two orientations. The möbius strip for example doesn’t admit any.

Comment: Party yes, a connected *orientable* manifold has exactly two orientations.

Comment: @user647486 but ← ← is in the same direction right? Wouldn't they be in the same equivalence class?

Comment: @Berci yes that's what I meant.

Comment: @Hawk Your two questions don't make sense. Same direction? Whats is direction? Orientation? I drew the two-component manifold as ${}-{}\ {}-{}$, but it is an abstract manifolds. I could have drawn it as $|{}\ {}/$. What equivalence classes? Equivalence classes are within the same tangent space (at the same point). Do you mean *consistent*?

Comment: @user647486 I am just saying this. Let $\Omega_p$ be the set of all (tangent) basis on a manifold $M$ at $p$. Select any ordered bases $(q_1,\dots,q_n)$ and $(w_1,\dots,w_n)$. Then they determine an orientation if $\det (J) > 0$, if not $\det J <0$. In either case, this puts out no more than two orientation.

Answer (score 2):

The concept of orientation arises in linear algebra by taking equivalence classes of ordered bases of real vector spaces, two such bases $\{b_i \}$ and $\{b'_i \}$ being equivalent if the linear automorphism sending $b_i$ to $b'_i$ has positive determinant. There are exactly two orientations of a vector space with dimension $> 0$.

Here you assign an orientation $\omega_p$ to each tangent space $T_pM$ and require that these pointwise orientations are "locally compatible". An orientation of $M$ is any such compatible family of pointwise orientations $\omega_p$, $p \in M$. It is not all clear that $M$ has an orientation, and in fact there exist non-orientable manifolds. Moreover, there are uncountably many families of pointwise orientations $\omega_p$, but most of them are not compatible. Moreover, in my opinion there is no a-priori reason why there should exist not more than two orientations. It is true for connected manifolds, but it requires a proof. For a manifold with $n$ connected components you get $2^n$ orientions.

Comment: I am just saying this. Let $\Omega_p$ be the set of all (tangent-pointwise) basis on a manifold $M$ at $p$. Select any ordered bases $(q_1,\dots,q_n)$ and $(w_1,\dots,w_n)$. Then they determine an orientation if $\det (J) > 0$, if not $\det J <0$. In either case, this puts out no more than two orientation.

Comment: Correct, there are exactly two orientations at each $p \in M$. But to get an orientation of $M$ you have to assemble a family $(\omega_p)_{p \in M}$ of pointwise orientations which are compatible in a suitable sense. Without the compatibilty requirement there are *uncountably many* such families, but compatibilty signficantly reduces the possible choices. There are manifolds with no orientation, connected orientable manifolds have exactly two and non-connected orientable manifolds have more than two (in fact , $2^n$ if $n$ is the number of components). But you need a *proof*.

Comment: I thought to talk about orientation you have to enforce the compatibility condition ($det J \neq 0$). I mean let's just take some simple (trivial) examples, if I take $M$ to be two disconnected line segments, there are still just two orientations (left and right).